# json data not working on server

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I retreived my json data using Jquery ajax. My data is:

```
[{"id":"2","checkNo":"74152","routingNo":"896523","accountNo":"741236","confirmAccountNo":"85263","custEmail":"avn@gmail1.com","custName":"jonita gandhi","custStreetAddress":"address2","custPhone":"78456","custCity":"city2","custState":"state2","custZipCode":"4123","amount":"71","memo1":"memo3","memo2":"","cmp":"support","bankName":"Federal Bank","bankAddress":"A-19, Golden avenue","bankCity":"Florida","bankState":"FE","isDeleted":"0","createdDtm":"2017-05-30 14:47:48","updatedDtm":null}]
```

On Jquery Success i hold the data in a variable

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

when i am trying to access checkNo. using jsonData[0].checkNo it yields **undefined** but when i check it using

```
console.log(jsonData)
```

It outputs data which is same as top.

**Note:** This problem yields only on server but it is working fine on my localhost.

**Edit:**

Here is my ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: postUrl,
data:queryString,
type: "POST",
success:function(data){
    switch(action) {
      case "edit": 
      jsonData = JSON.parse(data); console.log(jsonData);
      //var jsssss = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); console.log(jsssss); 
      $("#custEmail").val(jsonData[0].custEmail);
      $("#custName").val(jsonData[0].custName);
      $("#custCheckNo").val(jsonData[0].checkNo);
      $("#edit_model").modal();
        break;
     //some more code
}
});
```

Comment: Try removing `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @Arg0n after removing it works fine on my server but now, on localhost it says:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: I'd say on your server you have a `JSON string`, but on localhost it's an `object`. Try with: `var jsonData = typeof data === 'string' ?
 JSON.parse(data) : data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse and/or stringify your data. JQuery does this for you.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: postUrl,
    data: queryString,
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){
        switch(action) {
          case "edit":
          jsonData = data; 
          $("#custEmail").val(jsonData[0].custEmail);
    break;
    //some more code
  }
});
```

Comment: It worked for me. thanks. I wish i could upvote you. prior to this i was sending row data with & and on my php page i was using $_POST method to get it.

Comment: make sure you are sending data in json format like this:  queryString = '{"action":"' + action+ '", "checkId":"' + id+ '"}';  Key and value must be in doube codes.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your are stringifying your data two times

You don't have to `var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`

else do this

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
var data  ='[{"id":"2","checkNo":"74152","routingNo":"896523","accountNo":"741236","confirmAccountNo":"85263","custEmail":"avn@gmail1.com","custName":"jonita gandhi","custStreetAddress":"address2","custPhone":"78456","custCity":"city2","custState":"state2","custZipCode":"4123","amount":"71","memo1":"memo3","memo2":"","cmp":"Geeks Help","bankName":"Federal Bank","bankAddress":"A-19, Golden avenue","bankCity":"Florida","bankState":"FE","isDeleted":"0","createdDtm":"2017-05-30 14:47:48","updatedDtm":null}]';

var jsonData = JSON.parse(data); // remove your stringify

console.log(jsonData[0].checkNo)
```

Also, if you are doing anything like this in your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: '/Hello',
      data: { name: 'norm' },
      dataType: "json"
      success: function(data){
        //Here your data is already a parsed object
        var jsonData = data;
        console.log(jsonData[0].checkNo)
      }
   });
```

Comment: after removing it works fine on my server but now, on localhost it says:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 and when i receive Json data from server it doesn't contains ' as yours.

Comment: Share your ajax call. I think it has `content type` and `dataType` set

Comment: add contentType and Datatype as shown in my ajax call and don't parse anything your data will already be an object

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. I wish i could upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `JSON.stringify`.its already a json  string from php .try with

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

```js
var data ='[{"id":"2","checkNo":"74152","routingNo":"896523","accountNo":"741236","confirmAccountNo":"85263","custEmail":"avn@gmail1.com","custName":"jonita gandhi","custStreetAddress":"address2","custPhone":"78456","custCity":"city2","custState":"state2","custZipCode":"4123","amount":"71","memo1":"memo3","memo2":"","cmp":"Geeks Help","bankName":"Federal Bank","bankAddress":"A-19, Golden avenue","bankCity":"Florida","bankState":"FE","isDeleted":"0","createdDtm":"2017-05-30 14:47:48","updatedDtm":null}]';
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(jsonData[0].checkNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

just change by this

```
 var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

```js
var data ='[{"id":"2","checkNo":"74152","routingNo":"896523","accountNo":"741236","confirmAccountNo":"85263","custEmail":"avn@gmail1.com","custName":"jonita gandhi","custStreetAddress":"address2","custPhone":"78456","custCity":"city2","custState":"state2","custZipCode":"4123","amount":"71","memo1":"memo3","memo2":"","cmp":"Geeks Help","bankName":"Federal Bank","bankAddress":"A-19, Golden avenue","bankCity":"Florida","bankState":"FE","isDeleted":"0","createdDtm":"2017-05-30 14:47:48","updatedDtm":null}]';
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(jsonData[0].checkNo)
console.log(jsonData[0].routingNo)
```